# How to preview a large picture in quasar dialog?

Tags: css, quasar-framework, quasar

I need to use a dialog box to display a relatively large set of images to the user.
I want this image to be scaled when it exceeds the size of the dialog, but in any case no scrollbars should appear. And the image should be centered both horizontally and vertically in the main section of the dialog.

In normal html, I know that this can be set in two ways.

```css
.img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

or

```
.img {
    object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

However, since Quasar's Dialog Plugin doesn't seem to have a defined size, `max-height` doesn't have an effect.

You can reproduce this problem by reducing the height of the output window. When you drag the height to very small, a scroll bar appears on the dialog box.

How do I adjust it to achieve what I need?

The The code that I tried is here:

https://codepen.io/sshxmz/pen/vYryeWR

Comment: Maybe, you can just use a card with your css (style="max-width:100%...)
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/dialog#various-content